How to calibrate a NTC Thermistor using a manipulated Steinhart-Hart Equation?
I have a NTC Thermistor setup in a voltage divider to with a Arduino such that it can read me the temperature using the Steinhart-Hart equation.
I initially calibrated the thermistor and measured its resistance for temps of 0-100C, derived the A,B,C values for the Steinhart-hart equation that matches the measurements perfectly. Now when reading the temperature through the Arduino I get a discrepancy with respect to the the temperature: at true 18C my reading is 12C (-6C error), at true 55C reading is 51C (-3C error) and at true 95C my reading is 93C (-2C error).
Assuming my setup is all correct, with best choice of fixed resistor etc. how would I manipulate the Steinhart-Hart equation in the code to fit the erroneous readings to the true temp based on non-linear nature of the error.
I am already planning to add 2C like increasing the C value in y=mx+c to cover the minimum error of the high region but that still leaves to the curve to be fixed in the low and mid temp regions. Mathematically thinking, adjusting the steepness of the equation to make it less steep would be what I would be inclined to do.
Has anyone got ideas or input on the approach on manipulating the curve? Anything is greatly appreciated!

Please show your reference data, calibration calculations, and the circuit and code to read it.

What are the input offset voltages of your otherwise perfect set-up? What is the precise value of your power supply? What is the precise value of the ADC reference voltage. Have you performed an error analysis or budget? What about the accuracy of other components used?

How did you derive the A, B, C values from the temperature and resistance?  Also, you need 3 temperatures.

How exactly are you measuring the resistance with the Arduino? Have you confirmed that you can read the resistance of something simpler, say fixed 1% resistors, accurately over the range of interest?
